# Autoselect value in DropDownList2 based on selection made to the DropDownList1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am newbie to ASP.NET MVC 3.0. I am trying to autoselect the value in the DropDownList2 based on the value selected by user in the DropDownList1.

How I can implement this?

More details: DropDownList1 displays list of Cities and if user selects City1 then DropDownList2 auto-selects LakePopular (where DropDownList2 displays the unique thing about cities).

So far I am able to display both dropdownlist using ViewBag and SelectList in Controller.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the OnSelectedIndexChanged event of DropDownList1. This is executed server side and can compare the value and then set DropDownList2.

Example .aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_Changed">
<asp:ListItem Value="City1">City1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="City2">City2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
//
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2">
<asp:ListItem Value="City1">LakePopular</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="City2">Desert</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Example code behind:

```
protected void ddl1_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DropDownList2.SelectedValue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
}
```

Ofcourse you could do this client side using javascript but this way is quicker and easier. If you don't like the page refreshing then put it all inside an AJAX update panel.

Comment: I was looking for some example in MVC 3.0, razor engine instead of aspx.